# Python eps figure legend disappeared when insert in office

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, ms-office, eps

I saved my matplotlib figure in eps format, when I open it with GSView, it is OK, but when i insert it in WORD or PPT, the lengend and title all disappeared, then I ues the code below, it seems didnt work~  all number and text still missing.

So please help me here

PS: I am using windows 2007 system

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg') 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```